# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ProductId', table 'ProductDB.dbo.Brand';

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have two tables viz. tblProduct and Brands, tblProduct contains:
ProductId, ProductName, Quantity, Price, Entry_Date.
and Brands contains: ProductId, BrandID, BrandName, BrandDescription, DietType, ProductId(FK from tbProduct).

I'm using LINQ and want to insert this data into both tables on button click, here's the insert method:

```
protected void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tblProduct products = new tblProduct();

    using (ProductDataContext context = new ProductDataContext())
    {
        try
        {
            tblProduct prod = new tblProduct();
            {
                prod.ProductName = TxtProductName.Text;
                prod.Quantity = Int32.Parse(TxtQuantity.Text);
                prod.Price = Int32.Parse(TxtPrice.Text);
                prod.Entry_Date = DateTime.Parse(TxtDate.Text);
            };
            context.tblProducts.InsertOnSubmit(prod);
            context.SubmitChanges();

            Label2.Text = "Product Inserted";

            Brand br = new Brand();
            {
                br.BrandName = TxtBrandName.Text;
                br.BrandDescription = TxtBrandDescription.Text;
                br.DietType = TxtDietType.Text;
            };

            prod.Brands.Add(br);
            context.Brands.InsertOnSubmit(br);
            context.SubmitChanges();
            Label1.Text = "Done";
        }
        catch (Exception exe)
        {
            Label1.Text = exe.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to insert on both tables,but the insert command only works on the first table (tblProducts) but does not insert anything into the Brands table, I'm not certain what seems to be the issue here.
Please note that both the BrandID and the ProductId (on both tables) are set to auto increment.

Comment: Is there a constraint on the foreign key in the brand table to the product table? if so, you will need to include the productID that has been inserted into the product table in your insertion into the brands table

Comment: @RH6 thanks for responding early, yes the ProductId is a foreign key on the Brands table which I have also set to auto increment. Are you saying I should include something like prod.ProductId = br.ProductId ?

Comment: You will need to retrieve the primary key (productID) from the product table that you just inserted previously, and then when inserting into the brands table, the foreign key must match this, assuming they are 1 to 1.

Edit: Essentially what the answer I just posted says

Comment: `Brand` should also have a property `Product`. Use that instead of `ProductId` and call `SubmitChanges` once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this(note the ProductId)

```
                    Brand br = new Brand();
                   {
                      br.ProductId = prod.ProductId;
                      br.BrandName = TxtBrandName.Text;
                      br.BrandDescription = TxtBrandDescription.Text;
                      br.DietType = TxtDietType.Text;
                    };
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are inserting a record into a table with a foreign key constraint, the foreign key value of the record must be connected to the primary key it is referencing.

So when inserting the brand record, you will need to include this line:

```
br.ProductID = prod.ProductId;
```

this will allow the foreign key constraint to be maintained.

Edit: mike123 beat me to it, but you get the idea.